# how to save the ajax uploaded image before the object created in django?

Tags: ajax, django, model

here is my problem now.i want to create a group model,one of its filed is imagefile
 when people open that page to create the group.
he need fill in other fields .like group name ,group instruction,and group avatar,and i want use ajax to upload the picture to the server before he submit the whole page,give he a preview in that page.
the problem is ,in the host ,i get his picture uploaded via ajax ,and where i should save that picture path in database?
cause ,that group object has not created yet .

i should wait people click the submit button ,get he post all the data like group name ,and group instruction, and with that picture ,to call the save() function ,in this way i create the object.

how to deal with this kind of problem.

tanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create two kinds of Models - one for Picture object and one for Group object, then connect them with an id number.

For example, in your models class, make one like

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    profile_image = ImageField(... etc. read the reference below ...)
```

([here is the reference for ImageFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField))

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField... Whatever
    picture_id = models.ForeignKey('Picture')
```

([here is the reference for ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey))

So the idea is that you create a Picture separately, then link it to a Group through a ForeignKey.

Comment: yes one group only need one avatar ,however the problem is ,people may  upload  Multi times in  create the group  page.he may upload image1,then feel not good ,then upload imgae2,then try image3,in this way ,my host may get so many useless picture .how can i prevent this things happen.

Comment: hi,thanks ,i find a solution for stop the useless pictures in my host.yes i need create 2nd models in the same page when creating objects,this picture model only keep those temp picture.once people click the submit button,then i add the picture to the group model,and delete the temp picture.and all the temp pictures ,i save them to a temp folder ,i can delete all the pictures like every day or every week.thanks